# Custom boolean tag

Tags: macros, conditionals

I've created for my lessonbooks a boolean `studentversion` who can hide or reveal some teacher stuff under the advice of CarLatex. (see topic : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478695/169294)

Is it possible to link a key-word for true/false statement ? In my mind, I wish to have the boolean : 'version' who can be set to 'student'(true) or 'teacher'(false). So that I can write : `\setbool{version}{teacher}` rather than `\setbool{studentversion}{false}`.

A MWE will be :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


%%Current behaviour
\newbool{studentversion}
\setbool{studentversion}{false}

%%Desired behaviour
%\newbool{version}
%\setbool{version}{teacher}

\begin{document}

    \ifbool{studentversion}%
        {The studentversion boolean is set to true}%
        {The studentversion boolean is set to false}
\end{document}
```

Guess it's a detail but i'm sure it can help me to make my documents clearer for later use.

Comment: If you want to have multiple "audiences" there is also the `multiaudience` package that comes in handy.

Comment: @TeXnician I did not know that package. After i read the manual, seems it could be usefull. But i've already build my commands on the boolean. A simple \ifbool is sufficient to hide answers in a table at the moment. I keep in mind it for future improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion with an alternative syntax. We define a new command `\setversion` which takes either `student` or `teacher` as a parameter and sets the boolean value `studentversion` accordingly. For any other parameter an error is reported.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%%Current behaviour
\newbool{studentversion}
\setbool{studentversion}{false}

%%Desired behaviour
%\newbool{version}
%\setbool{version}{teacher}

\newcommand\setversion[1]{%
    \def\tempa{#1}%
    \def\tempb{student}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb
        \setbool{studentversion}{true}%
    \else
        \def\tempb{teacher}%
        \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \setbool{studentversion}{false}%
        \else
            \errmessage{Unknown value for studentversion: #1}%
        \fi
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

    \setversion{student}%
    \ifbool{studentversion}%
        {The studentversion boolean is set to true}%
        {The studentversion boolean is set to false}

    \setversion{teacher}%
    \ifbool{studentversion}%
        {The studentversion boolean is set to true}%
        {The studentversion boolean is set to false}

    % \setversion{other}%
\end{document}
```

outputs

> [image]

Comment: I was so obsessed to redefine tags (T/F) that i forgot to define a command who can set it. Pretty nice answer ! I like the `\errmessage{}` case. Thank you  !