# Compile twice by changing version and jobname

Tags: compiling, texstudio

Always making my lessons, i've defined some commands to separate `teacher` and `student` stuff. The structure is the same than what is described on this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494814/169294). A MWE is at the end.

At the moment, i've to compile one time, changing the name of the output, changing the `file.tex` to set the second version, recompile and rename this second output.

I want to make my life better by changing the `pdflatex` compilation command in `texstudio` to compile twice and changing automatically the `version` and the corresponding output.

I've read it's possible in the command line of `Texstudio` and i've read it's also possible with a bash file on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111009/compile-two-versions-of-a-document-from-the-same-latex-source). To be honest, i can't write/use/understand a bash so i prefer the first way.

How can i achieve :

- Compiling my `foo.tex` first with the option `\setversion{student}` and rename it as `foo_student.tex`
- Compiling second time (in the same run) my `foo.tex` with the option `\setversion{teacher}` and rename it as `foo_teacher.tex`

What I've done so far is to compile twice and create two pdf with different name but no differences on the contents with the following command :
`pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -jobname=%_student main.tex | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -jobname=%_teacher main.tex`

Here is a MWE for `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{studentversion}
\setbool{studentversion}{false}

\newcommand\setversion[1]{%
    \def\tempa{#1}%
    \def\tempb{student}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb
        \setbool{studentversion}{true}%
    \else
        \def\tempb{teacher}%
        \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \setbool{studentversion}{false}%
        \else
            \errmessage{Unknown value for studentversion: #1}%
        \fi
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\ProfDifference}[2]%
{%
    \ifbool{studentversion}%
    {%%True (student version)
        #1
    }%
    {%%False (teacher version)
        #2
    }
}


\setversion{teacher}  %%Modify this line to change the version
\begin{document}

    The following text depends of the version :

    \ProfDifference{It's the student version.}{It's the teacher version.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

In your `main.tex` change the `\setversion` macro to:

```latex
\newcommand*\checkversion
  {%
    \begingroup
    \def\tempa{student}%
    \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \ifx\tempa\myversion
      \setbool{studentversion}{true}%
    \else
      \begingroup
      \def\tempa{teacher}%
      \expandafter
      \endgroup
      \ifx\tempa\myversion
        \setbool{studentversion}{false}%
      \else
        \errmessage{Unknown value for studentversion: \myversion}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }
\checkversion
```

And change the call of `pdflatex` to

```sh
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -jobname=%_student "\def\myversion{student}\input{main.tex}" | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -jobname=%_teacher "\def\myversion{teacher}\input{main.tex}"
```

This should do. (I don't use TeXstudio, so I won't test this, but I see no reason this shouldn't work)

Comment: You made my day !  I've just switched `setbool{studentversion}{true}` into `\setversion{student}` to make my code more readable. Thanks you !

Comment: Note : In TeXStudio, compiling twice works only if you've checked the `advanced options`. Good to know for future readers. Otherwise, it only compiles the first file.

Comment: @Piroooh the `\checkversion` macro does also incorporate the functionality of your `\setversion`. If you want to use `\setversion` instead, you might as well do `\expandafter\setversion\expandafter{\myversion}` in your preamble and don't define a `\checkversion` macro.