# Generate two versions of a document using tagging package

Tags: xetex, teaching

I would to like to get in one run two PDF, the first one having this MWE :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tagging}

\begin{document}

\usetag{answer} 

\iftagged{answer}{Some text to be included in the first PDF}
\untagged{answer}{Some text to be included in the second PDF}

\end{document}
```

and the second one having this MWE :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tagging}

\begin{document}

\iftagged{answer}{Some text to be included in the first PDF}
\untagged{answer}{Some text to be included in the second PDF}

\end{document}
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: See https://ctan.org/topic/exercise and https://ctan.org/topic/exam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by the problem I encountered myself : [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510835/compile-twice-by-changing-version-and-jobname). I've adapted to your purpose. I'm not a XeTeX user but it works for latex and pdflatex.

The goal is to define a command `\myversion` to answer when you're compiling and to check version in your document to apply or not the `\usetag{}` macro. Using this way, you can compile twice by defining your compilation command either in texmaker, texstudio,... or in command terminal.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tagging}

\newcommand*\checkversion
{%
    \begingroup
    \def\tempa{answer}%
    \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \ifx\tempa\myversion
        \usetag{answer}
    \else
    \fi
}
\checkversion
\begin{document}

\tagged{answer}{Some text to be included in the first PDF}
\untagged{answer}{Some text to be included in the second PDF}

\end{document}
```

Afterwards, you can compile it with command line :

`latex -jobname=%_answer "\def\myversion{answer}\input{MWE.tex}" | latex MWE.tex`
The first makes the answer version and the second call the normal version.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: I finaly managed to make it work. I just can't find the command to add at the end of the comoilation line to show %_answer.pdf inside the internal viewer.

Comment: The internal viewer of latex editor (ie Texmaker, Texstudio...) is not designed to show two pdf in one. Here the normal version is displayed. If you want to switch, you may modify the command to write ```latex "\def\myversion{answer}\input{MWE.tex}" | latex -jobname=%_empty MWE.tex``` for the normal version and the editor should display the version with answers.